# The HDF5 library does not compile with -mcmodel=large

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, hdf5

I'm trying to compile a large scale FORTRAN application and need to link the HDF5 library to it. The program needs to be compiled with gfortran and  needs the **-mcmodel=large** options. When using only **-mcmodel=medium** I'm getting error messages like:

```
:(.text+0x3019): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.lrodata'
```

I'm compiling the HDF5 library using configure:

```
./configure --enable-static-exec --enable-fortran FCFLAGS="-mcmodel=large" CFLAGS="-mcmodel=large"
make -j
make install
```

When compiling the FORTRAN program, I'm getting:

```
H5_ff.f90:(.text+0x23): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `predefined_types_' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/ccHO0WzS.o
H5_ff.f90:(.text+0x3c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `predefined_types_' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/ccHO0WzS.o
H5_ff.f90:(.text+0x52): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `predefined_types_' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/ccHO0WzS.o
H5_ff.f90:(.text+0x68): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `predefined_types_' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/ccHO0WzS.o
H5_ff.f90:(.text+0x89): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `predefined_types_' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/ccHO0WzS.o
H5_ff.f90:(.text+0x9f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `predefined_types_' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/ccHO0WzS.o
H5_ff.f90:(.text+0xb5): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `predefined_types_' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/ccHO0WzS.o
```

I'm on linux and am using gfortran version: 4.7.2.

Compiling with **-mcmodel=medium** works, but only if I reduce the size of variables in the FORTRAN program. So, what can I do to compile a FORTRAN program with gfortran and the HDF5 libraries when using -mcmodel=large?

I can not show the real program here, but to get the idea, here is a fortran program which reproduces the error:

```
PROGRAM test
IMPLICIT NONE
DOUBLE PRECISION tst(1000,1000,1000,1),bf
COMMON /tt/ tst
bf = tst(1,1,1,1)
print *,'Hello World.'
call kk
END PROGRAM


SUBROUTINE kk
USE H5LT
USE HDF5
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER(KIND=4)::errcode
call h5open_f(errcode)
print *,"Hello Subroutine."
END SUBROUTINE
```

Compiling it with:

```
gfortran -o tst -mcmodel=large tst.f90 -I./hdf5/hdf5/include -L./hdf5/hdf5/lib ./hdf5/hdf5/lib/libhdf5hl_fortran.a ./hdf5/hdf5/lib/libhdf5_hl.a ./hdf5/hdf5/lib/libhdf5_fortran.a ./hdf5/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.a -lz -lrt -ldl -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,./hdf5/hdf5/lib
```

and assuming the HDF5 library in ./hdf5/hdf5. However, this program would compile and run with **-mcmodel=medium**, but my real program does not. I wasn't able to come up with a simple program which would not compile with **-mcmodel=medium**, but with **-mcmodel=large**. I'm not even sure why **-mcmodel=medium** is not working for the real program.

The HDF5 library is available here: http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html

Comment: Please show part with the declaration of the large arrays and the values of the dimensions. Even better, come up with a fully compilable example that still fails.

Comment: Right, I just did that. But as I explained in the question, this dummy program doesn't fully reproduce the problem.

Comment: Works for me `gfortran-4.7  -mcmodel=large large.f90 -I/usr/include  -lhdf5_fortran` --> `./a.out 
 Hello World.
 Hello Subroutine.
`  With my preinstalled hdf5 in OpenSUSE.

Comment: Find a code which fails for `-mcmodel=large` as you suggest in the first part of your question. How does the compilation command look like when you do your "When compiling the FORTRAN program, I'm getting:"?

Comment: Could it be the `--enable-static-exec` flag? I could be wrong but I thought that and the `-mcmodel=large` don't play nice together. How much memory do you have on your machine?

Comment: Do you use `large` or `medium` when "When compiling the FORTRAN program, I'm getting:" ??

Comment: @Timothy Brown, your guess were right, now the program compiles nicly, thanks a lot for that idea!, I thought that '--enable-static-exec' was really needed

Comment: @Timothy Brown, can you post your comment as answer?, then I can accept it

Comment: @Vladimir F, I was using this consistently, so medium with medium and large with large, the comment from Timothy Brown really solved this issue for me, however I don't really understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because your large array is in a `COMMON` block. This puts the array in the `TEXT` segment. By having this in combination with `--enable-static-exec` means the `TEXT` segment is over 2GB.

By removing the `--enable-static-exec` you are now using dynamic libraries and have managed to pull the `TEXT` segment down to below 2GB.

I dare say, if you need `-mcmodel=large` you should not mix it with `--enable-static-exec`.